# Can't open my iPad mini

Tags: ipad, startup

I shutdown my iPad and left it for a while.  Now I want to start it again and I can't open it.  I've used the sleep/awake button, also use that with the home button but I can't open it at all. It sits there with the Apple icon on the screen and sometimes it has a spinning little icon in the middle.  I sure would appreciate some help.

Comment: Maybe you need to charge it a bit...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assume that you have enough battery power on the iPadWhen you see the apple icon on your ipad, hold the power- and home button for several seconds. The ipad will turn off and back on again. After this you can release the buttons when the apple logo is visible.

When the ipad is still stuck on the loading screen, you could preform a DFU (device firmware reset)-reset. Do not forget: by preforming a dfu-reset, all data will be deleted from the iPad.

A tutorial on how to enter dfu-mode can be found [here](http://www.theipadguide.com/faq/how-do-i-put-my-ipad-dfu-mode)
Make sure that the ad is turned on before you start following the tutorial.

To check if you successfully entered dfu- mode:

- there should be an iTunes logo with a lightning/30-pins cable on the screen of the ipad
- when the device is connected to iTunes, you should get a popup that the device is in restore mode and it has to be restoren before it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [a DFU mode](http://www.iphonehacks.com/put-iphone-in-dfu-mode) and then restore.